# What is the number of elements of order 2 in $S_5$

Tags: group-theory

What is the number of elements of $S_5$ which are their own inverses equals?

An element $a$ is equal to its inverse means $a^{-1}=a$ i.e. $a^2=e$ i.e. the element must be of order 2, but I don't know how to determine the number of elements of order $2$. I took all the permutations and counted the number of permutations which are equal to their inverse and got $10$ elements. Is there any other efficient method to evaluate this?

Comment: ... or disjoint products (like unions, roughly speaking) of such cycles.

Comment: You haven't counted permutations like $a=(1~2)(3~4)$.

Comment: Header and body ask two slightly different questions: the identity permutation is its own inverse, but is not of order $2.$ I get $25$ or $26$ depending on which question you are asking.

Comment: Sorry I didn't think about identity. Header is the question. Body is how I wanted to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of order $2$ in $S_5$ can be written as either $(x_1 x_2) (x_3 x_4)$ or $(x_1 x_2)$ where all the $x_k$'s are distinct, so you just need to count all such elements.

This follows from the fact that every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles.